Is it possible to conditionally get a variable group using a variable?
I have a Variable group called "CI environments" with those variables:

CI_Branch1: Database1
CI_Branch2: Database2

I have a yaml pipeline with a variable called CIDatabase in a branch called Branch1
Can I set the value of CIDatabse like this?
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CIDatabase ]variables.$(TR_CI_${{variables['Build.SourceBranchName']}})"


Build.SourceBranchName is a predefined variable available in templates, so you don't need to set output variables.
Try using template expression syntax ${{ ... }} instead:
variables:
  - group: 'CI environments'

  - name: CIDatabase
    # e.g. if source branch name is 'dev' then variable value will be '$(CI_dev)'
    value: "$(CI_${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }})"

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Database: $(CIDatabase)"


If you want to use a dynamic variable value from variable group, you may use this sample:
variables:
- group: envs

stages:
- stage: A
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - job: SetVariableJob
    displayName: "Set Variable"    
    steps:
      - bash: echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=CIDatabase]$(TR_CI_${{variables['Build.SourceBranchName']}})'
      - bash: echo $(CIDatabase)

Variable group:

